# How to get reverse of number with specific base in java?

Tags: java, reverse, palindrome, radix

I am new to java. I was just writing a function to accept a number and its base as argument and then show the palindrome number (if any). The main problem is that I don't exactly get it **how to reverse the number of base other than 10?** The Code I wrote (according to my poor logic ) is below:

```
 void   CheckPalidrome(    int num,    int base)
    {
        long     n=num;
        
        boolean palid=false;
        long TNum= num;
        for(int i=1;    i<=10   &&  palid==false;  ++i)    
        {   
            int     rev=0;
            while(n>0 )
            {
                int d= (int) (n%base);
                rev=    rev*base  + d;
            
                n/=base;
            }
            if(TNum==rev)
            {
                palid=true;
            }
            else{
                n=TNum+rev;
                TNum=n;
            }
            
            System.out.println("TNum= "+TNum+"\trev="+rev);
        
        }
        
        if(palid==true){
            System.out.println("Palidrome= "+TNum);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("None, "+TNum);
        }
    }
```

But, there is a problem in this. It works fine for any number of base 10. But doesn't work for another base. For example:- 87 with base 10 will be reversed and checked if it is a Palindrome, if not it the reverse and number will be added and checked again Just Like:
**87+78= 165+ 561 = 726 + 627= 1353 + 3531 = Palindrome !**

But I don't know how to do this for other bases except 10.
Note: 1211 with base 3 forms Palindrome 112211 and 3112 with base 4 forms Palindrome 233332 . I used these results to test my code. But the output doesn't match.

---

Please forgive my poor English. Kindly share your knowledge or give me any idea to solve the problem. I shall be glad and thankful to you :)

Comment: what is requirement of base? what is used of second argument base?

Comment: Sir when i pass 10 as base in the 2nd argument (for decimal) it works fine. But if I give it another base like that of an octal (8). I gives wrong output. Kindly please mention the mistakes in my logic if you get it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic seems to be good, but remember to parse and print numbers in the given `base`.

E.g. the number `1211` (base 3) is the same as `49` (base 10).

To see this, I rewrote your code like this:

```
private static int findPalindrome(int num, int base) {
    for (int n = num, rev; n > 0; n += rev) {
        if ((rev = reverse(n, base)) == n)
            return n;
        System.out.printf("%-6s + %-6s", Integer.toString(n, base), Integer.toString(rev, base));
        if (base != 10)
            System.out.printf("   = (%-4d + %-4d) ", n, rev);
        System.out.printf("%n  = ");
    }
    return 0;
}
private static int reverse(int num, int base) {
    int rev = 0;
    for (int n = num; n != 0; n /= base)
        rev = rev * base + n % base;
    return rev;
}
```

Then tested it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test("87", 10);
    test("1211", 3);
    test("3112", 4);
}
private static void test(String num, int base) {
    System.out.printf("%2d: ", base);
    int p = findPalindrome(Integer.parseInt(num, base), base);
    System.out.printf("%-15s", Integer.toString(p, base));
    if (base != 10)
        System.out.printf("   = (%-11d)", p);
    System.out.printf("%n%n");
}
```

Which produced this output:

```
10: 87     + 78    
  = 165    + 561   
  = 726    + 627   
  = 1353   + 3531  
  = 4884           

 3: 1211   + 1121     = (49   + 43  ) 
  = 10102  + 20101    = (92   + 172 ) 
  = 100210 + 12001    = (264  + 136 ) 
  = 112211            = (400        )

 4: 3112   + 2113     = (214  + 151 ) 
  = 11231  + 13211    = (365  + 485 ) 
  = 31102  + 20113    = (850  + 535 ) 
  = 111221 + 122111   = (1385 + 1685) 
  = 233332            = (3070       )
```

The numbers in `()` are the base 10 numbers. The other numbers are shown in the `base` listed before the `:`.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! You are awesome :)